# Input loses focus after one character in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Input loses focus after one character is entered, it's on every single input in every component, I followed some videos exactly on React input but none of them work properly for me at all. I've tried using keys and rendering the inputs in separate components but nothing seems to work.

input and textarea is where its happening.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import "./bootstrap/css/landing-page.min.css";
import "./vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css";
import "./vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./vendor/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css";

import "./App.css";
import "./Group.css";

import store from "./store";
import Home from "./App";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  addBug,
  updateGroupID,
  getBugs,
  createAccount,
  deleteBug
} from "./actions/itemAction";

import { Container } from "reactstrap";

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Select from "react-select";

class Group extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: false,
      modalBug: []
    };
  }

  showModal = bug => {
    this.setState({ modalBug: bug });
    this.setState({ show: true });
  };

  hideModal = () => {
    this.setState({ show: false });
  };

  setBugTitle = e => {
    this.setState({ BugTitle: e.target.value });
    console.log(this.state.BugTitle);
  };
  setBugDescription = e => {
    this.setState({ BugDescription: e.target.value });
    console.log(this.state.BugDescription);
  };



  render() {

      if (
        this.props.user.loggedIn === true &&
        this.props.user.user.GroupID !== "NOGROUP"
      ) {
        return (
          <Provider store={store}>
            <div className="App">
              <link
                href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic"
                rel="stylesheet"
                type="text/css"
              />

              <nav className="navbar navbar-light bg-light static-top">
                <div className="container">
                  <Link to="/">
                    <div className="navbar-brand">Bug Buster</div>
                  </Link>
                  <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.authCheck}>
                    Log out
                  </button>
                </div>
              </nav>
              <div className="flex-container">
                <div className="bugSubmission">
                  <ul id="newBug">
                    <h3>Submit New Bug</h3>
                    <li>
                      //Input for Bug Title
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter Title..."
                        onChange={this.setBugTitle}
                        value={this.state.BugTitle}
                      ></input>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      //Input for Bug Description
                      <textarea
                        placeholder="Enter Description..."
                        onChange={this.setBugDescription}
                        value={this.state.BugDescription}
                      ></textarea>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <button
                        className="btn btn-primary"
                        onClick={() => {
                          const newBug = {
                            Title: this.state.BugTitle,
                            Description: this.state.BugDescription,
                            PosterName:
                              this.props.user.user.FirstName +
                              " " +
                              this.props.user.user.LastName,
                            PosterID: this.props.user.user.UserId,
                            GroupID: this.props.user.user.GroupID
                          };

                          this.props.addBug(newBug);
                        }}
                      >
                        Submit Bug
                      </button>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <Modal
                  show={this.state.show}
                  handleClose={this.hideModal}
                  bug={this.state.modalBug}
                ></Modal>

              </div>
            </div>



            <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
          </Provider>
        );
      } else {
        return <h2>No user logged in</h2>;
      }
    };

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <div className="App">
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
              <Route path="/group" exact component={Group} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.user,
  item: state.user,
  bugs: state.bugs
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  createAccount,
  updateGroupID,
  addBug,
  getBugs,
  deleteBug
})(Group);
```

Comment: you dont need bind for `setBugTitle` and `setBugDescription`. they are written in arrow function. just write  `onChange={this.setBugDescription}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to initialize **BugTitle** in the state

```js
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: false,
      modalBug: [],
      BugTitle: ""
    };
  }
```

and to invoke the **setBugTitle** function you can make it like that

```js
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter Title..."
          onChange={e => this.setBugTitle(e)}
          value={this.state.BugTitle}
        />
```

i hope that help you

Comment: That doesn't change anything